# could someone tell me why when the input is z or Z, it returns brackets rather than wrapping

Tags: python

```
def code_char(character, number):
characterOrd = ord(character)
characterNew = characterOrd + number
if 65 <= characterOrd <= 90:
    characterNew = characterOrd + number
    return chr(characterNew)
    if characterNew > 90:
        characterNewi = characterNew - 26
        return chr(characterNewi)       
if 97 <= characterOrd <= 122:
    characterNew = characterOrd + number
    return chr(characterNew)
    if characterNew > 122:
        characterNewi = characterNew - 26
        return chr(characterNewi)
elif " ":
    return chr(characterNew)
```

This is my function that shifts the letter to the right by the number inserted. Why when i input a number where it will mean the function needs to wrap back around to give a letter in the alphabet, does it not wrap around, i cant see the problem. Could someone please explain what is wrong with my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you return `chr(characterNew)` before checking whether it has gone past the limit.

So replace these:

```
return chr(characterNew)
if characterNew > 90:
    characterNewi = characterNew - 26
    return chr(characterNewi)
...
return chr(characterNew)
if characterNew > 122:
    characterNewi = characterNew - 26
    return chr(characterNewi)
```

By these:

```
if characterNew > 90:
    characterNewi = characterNew - 26
    return chr(characterNewi)
return chr(characterNew)
...
if characterNew > 122:
    characterNewi = characterNew - 26
    return chr(characterNewi)
return chr(characterNew)
```

However, I think there's more unintended behavior in the code.  If you give a shift-number so high that the character would wrap around *twice*,  the result wouldn't be alphabetic anymore.

For this, as a simple correction (using the modulo operation would me more elegant), I suggest replacing the `if` blocks by loops, like this (I also dropped the `characterNewi` variable; you can simply reassign `characterNew`):

```
characterNew = characterOrd + number
while characterNew > 90:
    characterNew = characterNew - 26
return chr(characterNew)
```

Finally, the method doesn't work for negative shift-numbers; maybe that wasn't the intention though.

Answer (score 1):

You can only return once from a function. In your if statement, you calculate `characterNew` and then immediately return the character. You don't even get to the nested if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are finishing the function with a return before it checks that the number is not "out of bounds":

```
def code_char(character, number):
    characterOrd = ord(character)
    characterNew = characterOrd + number
    if 65 <= characterOrd <= 90:
        characterNew = characterOrd + number
        return chr(characterNew) # Here the function finishes
        if characterNew > 90:
            characterNewi = characterNew - 26
            return chr(characterNewi)       
    if 97 <= characterOrd <= 122:
        characterNew = characterOrd + number
        return chr(characterNew) # Here too
        if characterNew > 122:
            characterNewi = characterNew - 26
            return chr(characterNewi)
    elif " ":
        return chr(characterNew)
```

Try with this fixed code:

```
def code_char(character, number):
    characterOrd = ord(character)
    characterNew = characterOrd + number
    if 65 <= characterOrd <= 90:
        characterNew = characterOrd + number  
        if characterNew > 90:
            characterNew = characterNew - 26
        return chr(characterNew)
    if 97 <= characterOrd <= 122:
        characterNew = characterOrd + number  
        if characterNew > 122:
            characterNew = characterNew - 26
        return chr(characterNew)
    elif " ":
        return chr(characterNew)

print code_char("z", 5)
```